# Faking $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’] in intranet?

Tags: php, apache, networking, spoofing

I've looked around for an answer to this question, but the answers are always situational - so here's mine:

**If a hacker is on a limited, local network, can they fake the IP in  $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’]?** (and out of curiosity - how?)

I understand that when it comes to the internet, any variable such as this can be wrangled into whatever you want. But in a local, wired network that may not even be connected to the internet at all, can they fake this address? I'm assuming that Mr.MissionImpossible is crawling along the ceiling with a notebook and Ethernet cable into one of the switches. The response in this scenario won't matter - but running the PHP script should only be limited from certain location(s).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’]` is populated with IP used to access apache server on TCP connection. If they managed to fake this on router, they can fake it.

Comment: So they would have to tell the router "this is my ip" and then connect to the webserver? What if the ip is already being used on the router?

Comment: Wanna start with this maybe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I get how this spoofing works now! :) So it would be possible to be at IP A, send to IP B, while pretending to be IP C. ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for definite if this can be faked in general, I would guess it probably can if you know what you're doing. But an intranet is a TCP/IP network with, in the case of a website, a HTTP layer over the top. The environment is essentially the same.

So if it can be done on the public internet, it can be done on your internal network too.